# How can I do an array on a js constructor function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I want to get the names of all the clients
which are stored in a constructor function.

```js
let Client = function(name, feedback){
this.clientName = name;
this.clientFeedback=feedback;
}

let client1 = new Client('Jo', 'Hello')
let client2 = new Client('Mark', 'Bye')

let clientKeys = Object.keys(Client);

For (let i=0; i<clientKeys.length; i++){
Console.log(Client.clientName)}
```

But this code doesnt work.

Can I use object.keys here?

I'm absolutely beginner, so I hope I'm asking well.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, so your `For` loop and `Console` aren't going to work. Generally speaking, instantiatable functions (i.e. `client`) should be uppercase.

Comment: Also, `Object.keys(client);` will return an empty array as `client`, since it is a constructor function, it doesn't have keys of its own, only instances like `client1` and `client2` do

Comment: I think what you actually want is `const clients = [client1, client2];` and `for (const client of clients) { console.log(client.clientName); }`

Comment: Also, if you want to get a client name you don't need neither `Object.keys` nor a `for` loop, just do `console.log(client1.clientName);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use `Object.keys` here?

No. I suspect what you actually want is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) (a [list data structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections))

```
const clients = [client1, client2];
```

and a loop through that:

```
for (const client of clients) {
    console.log(client.clientName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably thinking of something like this:

```js
function Client(name, feedback) {
    this.name = name;
    this.feedback = feedback;
}

let clients = [
    new Client('jo', 'hello'),
    new Client('mark', 'bye')
];

for (let client of clients)
    console.log(client.name, client.feedback);
```

The constructor function `Client` has no "memory" of its instances. Thus, you need to explicitly create an array or some other structure that keeps the references to the instances you are interested in.